# How could Madhu and Kaitabha have stolen the vedas before they'd been written down as scripture?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, hayagriva

How did  Madhu and Kaitabha "steal" the Vedas? ​How could the Vedas have been stolen by Madhu and Kaitabha when the Vedas hadn't yet been revealed as scriptures and written down in book form? And similarly, how could Lord Vishnu and Hayagreeva have recovered them?

Comment: Vedas are the hymns of creation. They are eternal sounds that are the breath of Brahman, and the basis of cosmos. They are not revealed. They are discovered. Anyone anytime can tune into them in the right state of deep tapasya. The word 'stole' is not literal stealing of a book. written scripts were developed only when human memory couldn't remember audio version. maybe madhu/kaitabh discovered the vedic mantras themselves. it's like pakistan developing a nuclear weapon by stealing our technology documents. it doesn't mean we lose them. it means they also have it.

Comment: if both brahma and asuras have the same power, then it will be chaos. so Vishnu didn't "recover" Vedas from them, he simply prevented them by abusing Vedic power by killing them.